# How to get dataset property without evaluate in puppeteer?

Tags: xpath, puppeteer

```js
const color = await page.waitForXPath('//*[@data-color]/@data-color');
console.log(await color.jsonValue());
// {}
```

This isn't right.  Compare how it works in Chrome's console:

```js
const color = $x('//*[@data-color]/@data-color')[0];
console.log(color);
// data-color="red"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems in puppeteer you get the [Attr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Attr) object, so you need to get its `value` property first:

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

const html = `
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head><meta charset='UTF-8'><title>Test</title></head>
    <body>
      <p data-color='red'>Text.</p>
    </body>
  </html>`;

try {
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  await page.goto(`data:text/html,${encodeURIComponent(html)}`);

  const colorAttr = await page.waitForXPath('//*[@data-color]/@data-color');
  const colorValue = await colorAttr.getProperty('value');
  console.log(await colorValue.jsonValue());
  // red
} catch (err) { console.error(err); } finally { await browser.close(); }
```